# double.parse(str) result is off by orders of magnitude

Tags: c#-3.0, windows-ce

I have a weird problem in converting a string to double in .NET 3.5. Here is my code:

```
   dbl = double.Parse(str);
```

When str is string with a simple double like "5.67" the result for dbl is 567.0.

Comment: @FosterZ: The post says "when str is a simple double like 5.67" so I assume str is "5.67"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess this is localisation issues and you need to use the [overload that specifies a format provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447.aspx).

The issue is likely that it is expecting `,` as a decimal separator and `.` as a thousand separator (and thus ignoring it in effect).

Example to reproduce possible issue:

```
string input = "5.67";
Console.WriteLine(Double.Parse(input, new CultureInfo("en-gb")));
Console.WriteLine(Double.Parse(input, new CultureInfo("de-de")));
```

This outputs:

```
5.67
567
```

Comment: thanks Chris. you're right. i changed my handheld device localisation to English and it's working. there is no need to overload format provider.

Comment: @mehrdad nekoupour: depending on what you are writing you may want to consider explicitly forcing a given interpretation of numbers in case somebody else running the software has their locale set differently. Also you may want to be aware of CultureInfo.InvariantCulture which can be useful for this type of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just editing Chris's answer:

```
value = "5.67";
double out;
style = NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol;
culture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB");
Console.WriteLine(Double.TryParse(value, style, culture, out number)?number:0);
```